# Best way to use additional components in wicket behaviors

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I've create a new subclass of a wicket behavior which can be attached to form components. If a validation error occurs for such a component, the behaviors shows/hides a specific error label. My code looks similar to this:

```
public MyErrorBehavior(Component errorComponent) { 
  // show/hide errorComponent within onUpdate() or 
  // onError() based on getComponent().isValid()
}
```

My questions is: Is it ok to pass a component to a behaviors constructor?

Cheers, 
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a behavior is allowed to keep references to components, please see EqualInputValidator as an example.

Take care if you remove these components from your component tree: you should remove the behavior too, otherwise you'll have dangling references of components which are no longer detached.

Comment: Thx for pointing me to an example. Concerning the dangling references: in my special the FormComponent and the associated error label are always removed together. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to keep a reference to the component because Wicket will pass the component in the callback method, e.g.

```
@Override 
public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) 
{ 
  // cast component to FormComponent and make the check here
}
```

This way there is no need to clean up and you can add the **same** Behavior instance to more than one (Form)Component.

Comment: That's true for behaviors interacting with its hosting Component. But in my case I have another Component (the error label) which I have to configure.